# How to retry with conditions in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am seeking the right syntax in Azure pipelines script to achieve the following. I have the below code but it's incorrect.

Overall: copy the egg file to Databricks only if there is no Databricks job running with the job name otherwise wait and retry after 5 min to check the status. Exit after 3 retries.

Step1:  Get the list of the status of the Databricks job matching a particular job name

Step2: Check if 'RUNNING' is one of the statuses from step 1

- if yes and first try: wait for 5 min and return to step 1
- if yes and fourth try: exit with error
- if no, copy the code and exit

```
      - script: |
          cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)
          retry = 0
          while [$retry -lt 5]
          do
            run_statuses=$(databricks runs list | grep $(jobname)| awk '{$1=""; print $3}' | sed "s/^[ \t]*//")
            if contains(run_statuses, 'RUNNING')
            then
                retry=`expr $retry + 1`
                sleep 1m
            elif contains(run_statuses, 'RUNNING') and retry=4
            then
                 exit 1
            else
                databricks fs cp --overwrite "pipeline.tar.egg" $(EGG_DEPLOY_PATH_PREFIX)latest/
                break
            fi
          done
        env:
          EGG_DEPLOY_PATH_PREFIX: EGG_DEPLOY_PATH_PREFIX
          jobname: jobname
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can retry within your bash script that's good.  In my case I want to retry because my bash script times out.  However, the general idea you can do is to take your logic and put it into a template (so you don't repeat the same logic over and over again)

On a successful run set a variable (note that to be safe don't reuse the variables) using `echo` for example

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=databrick]ok"
```

and combine with `continueOnError` and `condition`.

Here's the steps of the refactoring.

1. Starting from this where you want to retry that step:

   ```
   steps:
     - bash: |
         my 
         bash
         script
    - publish: etc
   ```
2. refactor to have the bash script in a template.

   ```
   # azure-pipeline.yml
   steps:
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - publish: etc

   # unreliable-script.yml
   steps:
     - bash: |
         my 
         bash
         script
   ```
3. add the variable set

   ```
   # azure-pipeline.yml
   steps:
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - publish: etc

   # unreliable-script.yml
   steps:
     - bash: |
         my 
         bash
         script
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=databrick]ok"
   ```
4. add the `condition` check and `continueOnError` and add `test`.

   ```
   # azure-pipeline.yml
   steps:
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - bash: |
         test "$MYVAR" == "ok"
       displayName: Verify that unreliable script ran correctly
     - publish: etc

   # unreliable-script.yml
   steps:
     - bash: |
         my 
         bash
         script
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=databrick]ok"
       condition: ne(variables['MyVar'], 'ok')
       continueOnError: "true"
   ```
5. repeat the template call up to a specific number of retries as desired.

   ```
   # azure-pipeline.yml
   steps:
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - template: ./unreliable-script.yml
     - bash: |
         test "$MYVAR" == "ok"
       displayName: Verify that unreliable script ran correctly
     - publish: etc

   # unreliable-script.yml as above
   ```